# What could be examples at calculus or introductory analysis level for the idea contained in the statement by David Hilbert?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, problem-solving

I read the following quote in the book "*As opposed to abstraction the art of doing mathematics consists in finding special cases which contain all the germs of generality.* --David Hilbert", however the author has not given any examples for the idea behind the statement.

What could be a example or some examples at calculus or introductory analysis level demonstrating the idea behind the above quote?

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: (@ littleO: internet search is showing it in many books.) Examples from subject will be difficult to collect together; but examples on specific topic are easy to show: For example, $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational in $[0,1]$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x$ irrational in $[0,1]$. This is one example to distinguish Riemann and Lebesgue integration on intervals.

Comment: Methods of Mathematics Applied to Calculus, Probability, and Statistics by Richard W Hamming, Chapter 1, section 1.5.

Comment: Cantor set. {}{}{}